# change div height when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div element that contain google map. The div is on the half of the page, and it's start from the middle (more or less).

Is it possible that the height of it will be expand when user scroll down ( and shrink when scroll up) ?

I have some script that do it, but it's not so friendly.

and the current script is:

```
// change map size when scroll down
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 450) {
        $("#map-warp").addClass("change-map-canvas");   // removed the . from class
        $("#map-warp").css("margin-top", "40px"); ;     // change margin from top for close infoWindow button
    } else {
        $("#map-warp").removeClass("change-map-canvas");  // removed the . from class
        $("#map-warp").css("margin-top", "10px"); ;
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the script is not so friendly'? Could you elaborate on this? The .scroll function as listed in your example would be the best way to implement this, so is your problem the resizing of your div?

Comment: @Sirence - well, you can see in the link i attached above that when you scroll down the map size change like a jump.

Comment: @roi have you tried my code below? it works like a charm for me. The map does not jump anymore. If so i would appreciate if you mark my answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var topMargin = 10 - $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 570) {
        $("#map-warp").addClass("change-map-canvas"); 
        $("#map-warp").css("margin-top", "40px");
    } else {
        $("#map-warp").removeClass("change-map-canvas");
        $("#map-warp").css("margin-top", topMargin+"px");
    }
});
```

Until the scroll reaches 570, the map will always stay like in the beginning. After that it will smoothly follow the scroll.

Comment: Perfect! thank you!
Can you explain in words what you done?